# Microsoft Graph OneDrive search text not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to search for files in a OneDrive folder. This was working a couple of weeks ago. However, now when running a query like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/[folder ID]/search(q='search string')` it returns an empty list. I'm trying it out using the Graph Explorer too (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and it works when checking the basic items contents of the folder, but the search just isn't working. I'm very new to using this kind of API to the extent that I'm not sure how to login to Microsoft's Q&A portal because I'm using a gmail account for the Azure setup etc and so the Q&A portal is giving me a 'use a work or school account' login blocker.

I've tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/[folder ID]/search(q='search string')` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='a')` as search options (both times an empty list of results), as well as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/[folder ID]/children` to check that the access to the Drive really was available (it was, returned items as expected).

Given that I'm now experiencing issues I'm not exactly 100% sure my memory is correct, but I'm pretty sure that this exact same type of search was working fine a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

It's working again today so I think it might have been a bug on their end but not sure, pretty strange